# Transliteration in Android Using GoogleAPI

Tags: java, android, transliteration

Need Help..!   I am working on Android Transliteration and I'm getting following 3 errors in my code.

```
1)GoogleAPI cannot be resolved

2)Translate cannot be resolved

3)Language cannot be resolved
```

I have properly imported all the required packages and also have added required external jar files. But unable to know where actually I'm going wrong.. 
    Following is my code snippet-->

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    EditText myInputText;
    Button myTranslateButton;
    TextView myOutputText;  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myInputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputText);
        myTranslateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.translateButton);
        myOutputText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
            myTranslateButton.setOnClickListener(MyTranslateButtonOnClickListener);
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener MyTranslateButtonOnClickListener 
      = new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String InputString;
            String OutputString = null;
            InputString = myInputText.getText().toString();

            try 
            {
                GoogleAPI.setHttpReferrer("http:\\www.google.com");
                GoogleAPI.setKey("API_KEY");
                OutputString = Translate.DEFAULT.execute(InputString,Language.ENGLISH, Language.HINDI);
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                OutputString = "Error";
            }
             Typeface customF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "akshar.ttf");
            //final TextView textV = (TextView) findViewById(...);
            myOutputText.setTypeface(customF);
            myOutputText.setText(OutputString);
        }

    };  
}

For your better understanding please have a look on following screenshots
```

Image-1 Packages Imported 
Image-2 Code that Contains Error
Image-3 My Build Configuration

[image: Packages Imported]

[image: Code that Contains Error]

[image: My Build Configuration]

Please help.. Thanks...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import these two:

```
import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;
```

& I think it would be better if you use the translation as a separate method.Check [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/) out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its working, Also needs to add google-api-translate-java.jar.  Thanks again..!